# Ruby Min and max from hour string array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to get the min and max values from an array of hour strings.

So, my array is:

```
["09:00", "11:10", "10:00", "20:00", "15:00"]
```

I've tried to use gsub on all elements to remove the `:` and convert to `int`, for later use `minmax` function, but unsuccessful. I don't want to make some uggly code just to solve my problem.

Is there any beautiful way to do that?

Comment: _"I've tried to use gsub on all elements to remove the : and convert to int, for later use minmax function, but unsuccessful."_ What did you try? Why was it unsuccessful? What was the result you got that wasn't the result you wanted?

Comment: @AlexWayne My mistake, was trying to parse the strings to int inside a loop instead using map or collect, so my problem was that I was calling function minmax outside the loop and the values inside was still strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have leading zeros:

```
["09:00", "11:10", "10:00", "20:00", "15:00"].minmax
  #=> ["09:00", "20:00"]
```

Comment: There advantages to using sensible ISO 8601 formats.

Comment: Cleanest answer with no doubt. Don't know what I did when I first tried something like this, but is working now.

Comment: To elaborate @muistooshort's comment about [ISO 8601](http://devblog.avdi.org/2009/10/25/iso8601-dates-in-ruby/), `require 'date'; Date::_iso8601("2014-09-17T22:31")
=> {:mday=>17, :year=>2014, :mon=>9, :hour=>22, :min=>31}`. and `["2014-09-17T22:31", "2014-10-02T12:01", "2014-09-17T22:30"].sort => ["2014-09-17T22:30", "2014-09-17T22:31", "2014-10-02T12:01"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to convert the values and to use max_by , and convert each string in a pair of two number

```
["09:00", "11:10", "10:00", "20:00", "15:00"].max_by{|e| e.split(':').map(&:to_i) }

=> "20:00"
```

Comment: In my case, I wanted to get min and max value. Tried here and could do with `minmax_by{|e| e.split(':').map(&:to_i) }`

Comment: You don't even need to `to_i` anything (assuming of course that all the times are 5 characters long).

Answer (score 1):

```
> a = ["09:00", "11:10", "10:00", "20:00", "15:00"]
=> ["09:00", "11:10", "10:00", "20:00", "15:00"]
> a.map(&:to_i).max
=> 20
> a.map(&:to_i).min
=> 9
```

Comment: (1) `20` is not in `a`. (2) What happens when `a = ['11:10', '11:11']`?

Comment: `20` is in `a`.  It's the 4th element.  As to the same hour different minute, valid point.  I read OP's question as not caring about minutes.

Comment: No it isn't, `'20:00'` is the fourth element.

Comment: Fair enough.  Again I read OP as wanting the min/max integer hour, not the actual element.